# Two Tables in SQL Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

beginner sql coder. I have an Access database with a customers table and orders table. The headers of the columns have a space (i.e: Shipped Date). I need to return Company Name, Contact Name, and Phone of customers who placed orders in March of 1998. Shipped Dates are formatted as 01-Mar-1998.

How do I do this? Access keeps giving me errors

```
SELECT Orders.*,Customers.CompanyName, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Phone
FROM Customers, Orders
(SELECT *
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers ON Orders.Order ID=Customers.Order ID)
AND Shipped Date BETWEEN #03/01/1998# AND #03/31/1998#;
GROUP BY Customers.CompanyName, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Phone;
```

EDIT:

New code

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.Customer=Customers.[Company Name]
WHERE Orders.[Shipped Date] BETWEEN #01-MAR-1998# AND #31-MAR-1998#;
```

The code runs, but Access prompts me to enter values for the all of the column names...Please help!

Comment: Can you please add the error message?

Comment: Your query is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is incorrectly formed. As we should enclose the coloumns with names containing spaces in `[]`
also tour GROUP BY was not relevant.

Now when we use `JOIN` we should have the query like :

```
SELECT * FROM Orders JOIN Customers ON Orders.[Order ID]=Customers.[Order ID]
WHERE Orders.[Shipped Date] BETWEEN #03/01/1998# AND #03/31/1998#;
```

Comment: ** Updated question with new info ** Thanks!!

Comment: See revision - it runs now (no error) but asks me to input variable values.

Comment: I don't think that the query will ask input at any cost...still are you declaring a function ?